# Word and PDF forms to be filled from excel using r or rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a two quite similiar forms - one in pdf format and one in word format and I am trying to fill the needed sections using rmarkdown. 
I have started with trying to read the documents in R and identify the locations need to be filled, but since the forms are quite long - I think that I'm missing something.
Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Please provide a [reprex]

Comment: The forms are in hebrew, so no use in adding them, 
I've used read_docx from textreader for the word and haven't really started mining the pdf. I assume that there's a faster automated method